# ScrollBar на custom control'е

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

Есть кастомный контрол

```
public partial class RichTreeView : Control
```

На нём делаю динамическое отображение текста с помощью метода `Graphics.DrawString` (отрисовка с помощью перегрузки с `RectangleF` параметром).
При добавлении элементов, текст уходит за пределы области контрола.

Вопрос: каким образом прикрутить `VScrollBar` и `HScrollBar`?

Есть вариант с добавлением `Panel` и помещением туда всего содержимого контрола, но я не уверен в его корректности.